# Unity sizeDelta of an Image update opposite to what it should

Tags: unity

I have an IEnumerator coroutine in which I call the UIManager script to update the Image size to fit the text size but it doesn't happen. when I use yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame() it sometimes solve the problem. but I don't want to use it.

edit: I tested the code like I was suggested in an empty unity project and it still happens, the width should change according to the text size but it happens opposite (when the text is small the width of the image is large and when the text is large the width of the image is small) (it only happens correctly at the first time - the width of the image fits the text width)

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image image;
    public Text text;
    private int k = 0;

    public void ButtonClick()
    {
        text.text = (k % 2 == 0) ? "10" : "10 / 10";
        image.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(text.rectTransform.rect.width, 30);
        k++;
    }
}
```

edit: Solved! thanks for the help, Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases() did the trick

Comment: You have typos in `UIManager.instace.DisplayPlayerScore();` and `UIManager.instace.UpdatePlayerScore(CalcaulatePlayerScore(playerHand));`--> should be `instance`. You should use IDE that will make you aware of typos.

Comment: @codeepic thanks I've changed it in the IDE, but that's not the problem, it was called 'instace' originally also.

Comment: @DMGregory I did what you suggested and I made the problem in a new unity project and it still happens

Comment: Thanks! Now it's much clearer what's going on. Looks like the UI system hasn't done its re-layout pass yet to update the size of the rectTransform based on the new text string, so you're still working from the old width when that next line runs. There may be a method you can call to [force a layout update immediately](https://forum.unity.com/threads/force-immediate-layout-update.372630/), or there may be a post-layout event that you can hook into.

Comment: Please post an Answer to explain your solution. Our system doesn't know to recognize "edit: Solved!" as an answer, so it will continue to consider this question unanswered until an Answer is posted below.